# Certificate requirements for Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

What are the technical requirements for a TLS certificate on Android 7+? I didn't found an official source for this, only [this recommendation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl):

> As of 2012, a 2048-bit RSA signature with an exponent of 65537 expiring yearly is acceptable. When rotating keys, you should check for recommendations from an authority (such as NIST) about what is acceptable.

I'm looking for concrete requirements like key length, expiration date, SHA requirements, TLS version, SAN extension, ... like [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) does. Also are there special requirements for the CA/intermediate if self-signed?

Comment: Your Apple link seems a bit outdated as it does not mention certificate transparency and the maximum certificate validity has been shortened to AFAIR one year. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205280 https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211025

Comment: @Robert: You are right, that was more of an example. But thanks for the first link. I didn't stumble over it yet.